# chicken/turkey/red meat diet

Tags: diet

I am 173cm, 67 kg 30 yo male. I have about 12% fat ratio. I want to drop 1 kg fat and gain 4 kg muscle in couple months. I do go to gym 3 times a week and using protein shaker twice a day. I am on low carb diet. what is suggested amount of chicken/turkey/red meat that I should consume every day?

Comment: 12% is pretty low already, why do you want to go below that?

Answer (score 1):

Dropping 1 kg och fat while adding 4 kg of muscle in "a couple of months" is impossible for most people

Adding 4 kg of pure muscle in a year is something that can pretty much only be achieved if you're completely new to lifting, if you work out perfectly and if you eat perfectly.

You should aim for as large gains as possible though, and to achieve that, I would recommend that you first lose the fat and then go for a modest bulking phase, aim for 2 grams of protein per kg of body mass. There isn't really any evidence for larger gains with more protein than that.

Wether you get your protein from meat or protein drinks doesn't make a huge difference. You might want to get some creatine if you eat low amounts of meat though.

Comment: I might be wrong, but i have read articles that "say" that high protein intake helps burn fat.

Comment: Well protein has a high thermic effect when being metabolised, not sure if that factor is included in the listed energy content in food, but I think it is. Protein will shift you towards storing protein or losing fat, depending in your total energy balance, but only to a certain point, and that point seems to be around 2g/kg.

Comment: I do agree with the 2g/kg or 1g/pound